# Pentaho - Sum of a Column based on a Column Condition

Tags: pentaho

I need to add 2 columns that sum the exactly column based on operational code condition
Example: operational_loss ( sum of cost column with operational code 30 and 25)
inventory_loss (sum of cost column with operational code 26 and 28)

Tried with Formulas and Stream Lookup

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a group by? You group by operational code and add the cost column for each value of the operational code. You can use a value mapper before that to map all different operational codes to the desired group.